# Turning variable image sizes into same size thumbnails

Tags: html, image, grid, thumbnails, crop

I am trying to display a grid of images on my website. The problem is they are all different sizes which makes it look really sloppy if you use a really wide or really elongated image. Is there any resources you could suggest to help with this problem. I would like to make a grid of images that are all the same size. A cropping function similar to Facebook profile picture system would work great.

Comment: Here is an example of what I am looking for. Though I would make it a static width and height with zoom and pan options.http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/seo-tools/favicon-generator-crop-images/

Comment: This is even closer to what I am looking for although it is not functional: http://jsfiddle.net/gCqJ4/

Answer (score 0):

I found a website that is exactly what I need. There is a [website](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop) that maintains the aspect ratio and has a nice interface. I think I will implement this on the site.